# Exponent combinations

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I have Mathematica represent the product of two different bases and exponents as a single power (where possible)?

For example, see the product below can be expressed below:

`2^25 * 3^40 == 209952^5`

I am wondering if I have to use a [ResourceFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/category/symbolic-numeric-computation). But not sure which one! Or is there a local function?

Would be nice if Mathematica can show the steps also in how to derive that!

Comment: What is the expected result in your example? And if you don’t know it for that one, then can you show a simpler one? In general, it seems that $b$ would be the logarithm in base $a$ of your number; but I have a feeling that you are looking for integer a, b? It would seem to me that it won’t always be possible to do that.

Comment: Updated P.S. section above with the solution

Comment: Think about `(2^25)^(1/GCD[25,40])*(3^40)^(1/GCD[25,40])` and what that might do for you.

Comment: Ah, @Bill beat me to it: `With[{cf = GCD[25, 40]}, {Inner[Power, {2, 3}, {25, 40}/cf, Times], cf}]`.

Comment: Simpler `(2^25*3^40)^(1/GCD[25,40])`

Comment: Interesting! wow...Good way to look at this!  So you just take the (in this case) 5th root of the expression. Now if those 2 numbers did not have a GCD, I guess then any other Real numbers would have done.   Ex:  Table[FindInstance[a^b == 2^25 * 3^40, {a, b}, PositiveIntegers] , 1]

Comment: I meant:  Table[FindInstance[a^b == 2^25*3^40, {a, b}, Reals], 5]   as 5 Real samples... But why can't Mathematica find the PositiveIntegers above? I noticed it spun for couple minutes then gave up!

Comment: Ah, but all numbers, or at least all sensible numbers, have a GCD. Sometimes just==1. So 3^2*5^3==1125^1 because the GCD==1.  Why your `FindInstance` with `Reals` didn't find this is might be because there are an infinite number of different `Reals` a,b that satisfy this, can't know. If I change that to `Integers` it quickly gives up because the problem doesn't seem posed in a way that Mathematica sees a clear algorithm or choice of integers to pick. And my `FindInstance` doesn't understand `PositiveIntegers`

Comment: @Bill: PositiveIntegers in a feature of the latest version of Mathematica only. As per Reals, it does find, I limited it to 5 and got answers. But it really strikes me as odd why it cannot find Integer solutions, as it's a fast tool and should be able to go through all combos in relatively fast time to come up with that. This is highly strange. Even if it uses any algo. But the GCD method is superb! Thx (as the powers inside the nth root cancel-out/simplify the root - leaving behind integers) - btw why didn't you just post this as a "Solution" here?

Comment: Just use the "unique factorization of integers theorem" (a.k.a. "Fundamental theorem of arithmetic"). For example, let m>0 be a positive integer and choose any integers a,b, and c from the set {0,1,...,m}. Put X=2^a*3^b*5^c and Y=2^(m-a)*3^(m-b)*5^(m-c). Then we always have X*Y=(2*3*5)^m. If you are given X and Y in the first place, then you can use FactorInteger[] to find exponents a,b,c.

Comment: Yes Nice generalization Kato! Thank you.